# In python, is there a way to automatically substitute for missing values?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to parse a JSON object that consists of an array of objects. Each object contains several fields, but fields are often missing.  Here's an example:

```
{
    'objects' : [{
        'fieldA' : 1,
        'fieldB' : 2,
        'fieldC' : 3,
    },
    {
        'fieldA' : 7,
        'fieldC' : 8,
    },
    {},
    {
        'fieldB' : 1,
        'fieldC' : 0,
    }]
}
```

I'd like to convert each of the fields into a list, preserving the ordering of the objects, the equivalent of this:

```
fieldA = [1,7,"Missing","Missing"]
fieldB = [2,"Missing","Missing",1]
fieldC = [3,8,"Missing",0]
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I can come up with ways to do it that involve a lot of 'if' and 'in' statements and repeated iteration over lists. But it seems like there should be a more pythonic way to do it, something like:

```
fieldA = [ (obj.fieldA | "missing") for obj in json.objects]
```

Does python syntax allow something like this?

Comment: I didn't know there was a [tag:missing] tag.

Comment: You know, I didn't even think about that.  I guess it is kind of a strange tag.  Worked in this case, tho.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need the `dict.get()` method:

```
fieldA = [obj.get("fieldA", "missing") for obj in json["objects"]]
```

Note that the items of a dictionary are accessed with `["key"]`, not with `.key`.